# java inheritance best practice?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have below classes.

```
public class BaseRequest {
    protected List<Emp> names;  // names property is required in many classes 
}

public class FirstRequest extends BaseRequest {

    public FirstRequest() {
        names = new ArrayList<Emp>();
    }

    public setNames(List<Emp> names){
        super.names = names;
    }

    public List<Emp> getNames(){
        return super.names;
    }
}

public class ServiceClass {

    public void someMethod(List<Emp> emps) {
        FirstRequest request = new FirstRequest();
        request.setNames(emps);
        //Some Logic
    }
}
```

Am i doing inheritance in right way? how i can i improve it further?

Thanks!

Comment: use `BaseRequest request = new FirstRequest();` instead of `FirstRequest request` in side the `ServiceClass`

Comment: @SantoshJoshi then he needs to declare the getters and setters on the superclass also, while it could be abstract and implement them.

Comment: Why is `names` defined in `BaseRequest` but the setter and getter as well as the initialization in `FirstRequest`? There might be reasons for this but unless it's on purpose, move that code to `BaseRequest` as well.

Comment: Looks okay, but we do not have any context.

Comment: If you have a protected Attribute in in your super-class every other class in the same package can directly access it. This is uncommon and I would recommend not to do that.
In the consequence you would need to move the getters / setters and the Contructor that initialises the NamesList to the Superclass. That would lead to a common pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How i can i improve it further?

Move the methods related to `names` into the base class, and make `names` `private`.

```
public class BaseRequest {
    private List<Emp> names = new ArrayList<Emp>();

    public setNames(List<Emp> names){
        this.names = names;
    }

    public List<Emp> getNames(){
        return names;
    }
}

public class FirstRequest extends BaseRequest {
    // the rest of your stuff
}
```

You should avoid making `names` protected: a public getter should be good enough for derived classes and for the other users of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do, for this piece of code most things seem okay.
Might want to change

```
FirstRequest request = new FirstRequest();
```

to

```
BaseRequest request = new FirstRequest();
```

And use getters / setter in the superclass.

Also, in the constructor of the FirstRequest, you should talk to the super class (do the ArrayList initialisation there for example)

```
 public FirstRequest(){
 super();
 }
```

and in the super class

```
public BaseRequest()
{
// initialisation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `BaseRequest` to an interface and provide only the signatures of the methods to be used by the clients. The client should be interested only to the methods provided (`api`), not the implementation details Then you can implement them in all classes implement the interface. It is more flexible with an interface:

```
public interface BaseRequest {
    List<Emp> getEmps();
    void setEmps(List<Emp> list);
    ....
}


public class FirstRequest implements BaseRequest{

    List<Emp> getEmps(){
        return ...;
    }

   ....
}
```